# How does this bundle of gradients and a divergence equal these gradients and Hessians?

Tags: vector-analysis

In words it may be vague, but my question is: why does 
$$
\nabla \cdot (\nabla f \cdot \nabla g) = Hess(f) \cdot \nabla g + Hess(g) \cdot \nabla f)
$$
In d dimensions?

Edit: After the hint, I was able to manage the problem. Thanks to Blue Raincoat.

Comment: Product rule. Have you tried it? It's $(f'g')'=f''g'+f'g''$ with some indices.

Comment: @FamousBlueRaincoat Ah! You have hit the nail on the head. Ironically, in the past hw I missed every problem that required a product rule because I didn't see it applying